# Javascript - If not in array then add - if in array then update qty

Tags: javascript

Below is my code for a simple shopping cart, the only problem is the items from the first box work fine, however the second box does not.

[http://itsuite.it.brighton.ac.uk/ols11/cart](http://itsuite.it.brighton.ac.uk/ols11/cart/) - add the "bumblebee" item, and then repeat and it counts correctly. Now try the second drop down a few times.

Javascript:

```
var ids = []
var names = []
var qtys = []
var prices = []
var total = []


function newcart (id, desc, qty, price)
{
    var lengthofid = ids.length
    var i = 0
    while (i < lengthofid)
    {
        if (id == ids[i])
        {
            qtys[i] = parseInt(qtys[i]) + parseInt(qty)
            prices[i] = parseInt(prices[i]) + parseInt(price)
            i = lengthofid + 1;
        }else{
            ids.push(id)
            names.push(desc)
            qtys.push(qty)
            prices.push(price)
        }
        i++

    }
    if ( i == 0 )
    {
        ids.push(id)
        names.push(desc)
        qtys.push(qty)
        prices.push(price)
    }
    alert(names)
    alert(qtys)
}
```

---

Comment: Just FYI, clicking on your page redirects me to the mainsite

Answer (score 0):

you have two forms in this page and the select tag having the same name 
then you should call the function like this

first drop down in first form item1:
try this

```
newcart(item1.prodid.value,item1.desc.value,item1.qty.value,item1.price.value);
```

first drop down in first form item2: 
and try this

```
newcart(item2.prodid.value,item2.desc.value,item2.qty.value,item2.price.value);
```

and so is desc and price
and i think having two forms like this is not encouraged especially for
compatability issues in IE will not work "in my case form inside form"

Comment: I have just updated tgt HTML with what i think you mean - it did not seem to make a difference. Anyother help?